# Delays when uploading archives to Amazon Glacier using boto3 from a NAS box

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to backup local files to Amazon Glacier using the boto3 Python library on my NAS box (Zyxel NAS326 running Python 3.7 on entware-ng). While this generally works, I found that the upload speed is extremely slow. To rule out general problems with the NAS box or my internet connection, I did the following:

- Running my backup program on my desktop computer: maximum upload rate used
- Uploading a file to the internet from my NAS box using FTP: maximum upload rate used

On my router I could see that there are only short peaks of outgoing data followed by long delays.

To narrow down the problem I have logged the file access during the upload. This showed that there is no delay reading from disk, but during the sending of the data via the HTTPS connection. It turned out that a chunk of data is read from the file (usually about 9 MB) then there is a short activity on the internet connection, then a delay of minimum 10 seconds before more data is read from the file. So it seems that the connection is somehow blocking the upload, but I have no idea why, or what I could do about it.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or has ideas what else I could try?